# How to use a a trained model

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, linear-regression, data-science-model

I just trained my first model in Python 3.7/scikitlearn (Linear Regression) (well I copied most of the code but its something ^^).

Now I want to actually Use the model. Specifically its about sons heights incorrelating to their fathers. So I now want to enter a new Father-height and get a predictions for its sons height.

How could something like this look like?

I read about "Pickle" to save a model and use it later, seems awsome but how would I use such a saved model?

If anybody can give me a simple answer or even just a link to atutorial would be great. Below is a piece of "my" code just for some context.

```
#Spliting the data into test and train data
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)

#Doing a linear regression
lm=LinearRegression()
lm.fit(X_train,y_train)

#Predicting the height of Sons
y_test=lm.predict(X_test)
print(y_test)
```

Comment: The link https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-machine-learning-models-python-scikit-learn/ is just to add to the answer by Gyan Ranjan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your model saved as the variable `lm`. You can use the `lm.predict(X_test)` for any other test scenario. Note that your `X_test` should be similar to your `X_train` meaning if you have transformations made on your `X_train`, you need to do similar transformation on `X_test` too. You can use pickle in the following way

```
import pickle
filename = 'model.pckl'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))

#To load the model from disk, use this
model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
prediction = model.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Awsome, Thanks. Quiet easy actually ^^. I cant abvote yet but I "accepted" your anwer. (The link is perfect, very easy to understand)
I assume that Pickle is the standard next to anybody uses for storing a model? just to get started with the right tools ^^

Comment: Yes. One other way to go is to dump the model into a json and also dump the trained weights . While loading the model, you need to then define the model architecture and also load the weights after compiling. You can find lot of links explaining it.

Comment: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/ 
Have a look here for the json way of saving the model